# XML: horizontal spacing & line spacing between elements

Tags: xml, text, checkbox

This XML code results in the checkbox and text being on the same line but with about 40 spaces betweenthe text and the checkbox.  Is there a way to control spacing?  Thanks in advance!

```
<element xsi:type="Checkbox">
    <class>AllProYes</class>
  </element>
  <element xsi:type="Text">
    <value>SalesPRO </value>
  </element>
  <element xsi:type="Checkbox">
    <class>AllProYes</class>
  </element>
  <element xsi:type="Text">
    <value>SalesPRO w/Lending Access </value>
  </element>
  <element xsi:type="Checkbox">
    <class>AllProYes</class>
  </element>
  <element xsi:type="Text">
    <value>TellerPRO </value>
  </element>
```

Comment: I guess this is XML that is read by some rendering tool. If that is the case, you will get much better answers if you tell us what that tool is.

Comment: This XML does not "result in" anything. It's some program processing this XML that "results in" the effect you are describing. This is a question about that program, not about the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With System.Xml, you can turn off [PreserveWhitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). With MSXML, you can set [preserveWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to false before loading the xml.